# Populating a Rails class in the migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, migration

I'm trying to create a migration for a simple table that is just used as an enum. So I want to populate the table immediately with its values. I tried the following:

```
class CreateUserTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
    create_table :user_types do |t|
      t.column :type, :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_types
  end

  UserType.create :type => "System administrator"
  UserType.create :type => "Simulation controller"
end
```

but I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Could not find table 'user_types'
```

I was following the [Rails wiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.com/rails/pages/UnderstandingMigrations) and expected it to work.

---

Thanks. But what you suggested doesn't seem to be working. Well, I can't see the strings.

```
sqlite> select * from user_types; 
1||2009-02-08 12:00:56|2009-02-08 12:00:56 
2||2009-02-08 12:00:57|2009-02-08 12:00:57
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of two answers already given, but this should work for you:

```
class CreateUserRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :user_roles do |t|
      t.string :role
      t.timestamps
    end

    UserRole.create :role => "System administrator"
    UserRole.create :role => "Simulation controller"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_roles
  end
end
```

Rename your class UserType to UserRole (along with the associated test classes, assuming you created all of these using the generators). Rails uses the 'type' column for single table inheritance, and automatically populates the field with a class name when you have models that derive from a base class.

Comment: Just wondering, why is 't.string' used instead of 't.column'? It's the first time I've seen it in a migration.

Comment: @alamodey - t.string replaced t.column in rails 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class CreateUserTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table :user_types do |t|
      t.string :role
      t.timestamps
    end

    UserType.create :role => "System administrator"
    UserType.create :role => "Simulation controller"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_types
  end

end
```

It is the self.up method that runs by default when you call rake db:migrate

Edit: changed column name to 'role' as 'type' is reserved for single table inheritance. (See comments). Apologies to Kyle Boon for ending up with a very similar answer.

Comment: Next question: What do I need to do so rake db:migrate will update the database after making changes to the migrations file. rake doesn't seem to work as well as make does for C.

Comment: Each migrations file is run sequentially. If you make changes to a migration file, you should rollback to that version and re-run. Alternatively you could write a further migration file which makes the change you need on top of the original.

Comment: This still does not work, possibly because (as someone in this thread said) the 'type' column is reserved.

Comment: Yes - I think that is exactly it.  I will update my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

A bit off topic but worth mentioning:  It is considered poor form to instantiate data in  migrations because the "official" way to create databases in the production environment is

```
rake db:schema:load
```

which of course will not load your data from a migration file.  You may want to have a look at one of my favorite plugins for this: Seed_Fu.

With Seed_fu, you create your data fixtures in YAML and then issue a

```
rake db:seed
```

When you want to get the data set up.

Answer (score 0):

HermanD's answer should work. I want to point out though, that you should be careful about using a column named 'type' AFAIK , Rails uses that column name for STI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the create statements inside
   self.up
2. Call **`UserType.reset_column_information`**
   after creating the table and before
   populating it. The model UserType is
   loaded before creating the table, so
   rails has collected information
   about database structure before the
   table will exists. You need to reset
   it so Rails will inspect table
   attributes again.
3. Don't use 'type' as an attribute name. Its used for STI.

   class CreateUserTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration

   ```
   def self.up
     create_table :user_types do |t|
       t.column :role, :string
       t.timestamps
     end

     UserType.reset_column_information

     UserType.create :role => "System administrator"
     UserType.create :role => "Simulation controller"

   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :user_types
   end
   ```

   end